# How to load events from RDBS PostgreSQL using Axon 3.3.3 version?

Tags: axon

Axon Version: 3.3.3

I would like to load(read) events from PostgreSQL DB, I couldn't able to find the right configuration, Could you please share the config details to read event from domain_event_entry table.

Below is the current configuration to store events in Database

@SpringBootApplication

public class UserServiceApplication {

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
    SpringApplication.run(UserServiceApplication.class, args);
}

@Bean(name = "userAggregateFactory")
public AggregateFactory<UserAggregate> userAggregateFactory() {

    SpringPrototypeAggregateFactory<UserAggregate> aggregateFactory = new SpringPrototypeAggregateFactory<>();
    aggregateFactory.setPrototypeBeanName("userAggregate");

    return aggregateFactory;

}}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you are in a Spring Boot environment, I am assuming you are using the `axon-spring-boot-starter` dependency to get everything wired up.
Thus, that means Axon will create all the required beans for you, like the `CommandBus`, aggregate `Repository` and also the `EventStore`.

In the majority of Axon applications, you are not required to retrieve the Events from the `EventStore` yourself. You can simply have a class with `@EventHandler` annotated methods on it. If this class is a Bean in a Spring environment, Axon will automatically register it as being capable of handling events. This would thus omit the need to query the events yourself directly.

However, if you need to read a set of events, I would suggest to wire the `EventStore`, as it contains the methods to retrieve a stream of events.

Lastly, I highly recommend to increase the Axon Framework version you are using. Axon Framework 4.0 has been released almost over a year now. Active development **no longer** takes place on Axon 3.